# How to read Azure Databricks output using API or class library

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect, databricks-cli, spark-bash-azure-databricks

I have Azure Databrick notebook which contain SQL command. I need to capture output of SQL command and use in Dot Net core.
Need help.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot capture results of Azure Databricks Notebook directly in Dot Net Core.
Also, there are no .NET SDK's available and so you need to rely on [Databricks REST API's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/) from your .NET code for all your operations. You could try the following -

1. Update your Notebook to export result of your SQL Query as CSV file to file store using **df.write**. For example -
   `df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").save("sqlResults.csv")`
2. You can setup a Job with the above Notebook and then you can invoke the job using Jobs API - [run-now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs#--run-now) in .NET
3. You need to poll the job status using the [runs list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs#--runs-list) method to check the job completion state from your .NET code.
4. Once the job is completed, you need to use the [DBFS API - Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/dbfs#--read) to read the content of the csv file your notebook has generated in step 1.